# Adding recoil to an FPS game using C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ive been trying to add recoil to my fps game (Used Brackeys tutorials for the base), but the camera looking script is causing the rotation to be set each frame. I cant figure out how to change the camera rotation without the script resetting it

Code for the looking script is attatched below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
```

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public float mouseSensitivity = 1500f;

public Transform playerBody;

float xRotation = 0f;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;  
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
    playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
}
```

}

Comment: why not change the value of xRotation?

Answer (score 0):

To change the camera rotation without the script resetting it I would use an `if` statement to check if a different rotation should be applied ex:

```
bool canLook = true;

if(canLook == false) {
//apply your desired rotation
}
else 
{
//run your looking code
}

//When you want to apply your rotation set canLook to false
//And when you want to return to the camera movement set canLook to true
```